# How to make a list from most lengthy string to least lengthy string in java

Tags: java

I'm making a minecraft mod menu (That sounds even worse on here) and Im trying to make the string variables appear from most lengthy to least lengthy
I.e:
"Chest Stealer"
"Player ESP"
"Flight"
"Speed"
"box" etc.

Here is my current code:

```
for(Module m : myClient.getModules())
    {
        if(m.isToggled() && m.getName() != "Click GUI" )
        {
            modules.add(m.getName());
            for(int i = 0; i < modules.size();i++)
            {
            int currentModule = i;
            for(int j = 0; j < modules.size();j++)
            {
                if(modules.get(currentModule).length() > modules.get(j).length())
                {
                    int currentPos;
                    currentPos = modules.indexOf(i);
                    modules.set(modules.indexOf(j), modules.get(i));
                    modules.set(currentPos, modules.get(j));
                }
            }
```

Every time I try and tackle this problem I end up forgetting what I wanted to do mid-coding or it just doesnt work. Current, while
1 mod is active: Draws the mods name, no problem
2 mods are active: Leaves the mod that was activated first on top and draws the second mod's name twice below.
3+ mods are active: crashes.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciate, Thanks everyone

Comment: I think you would benefit from the [Sorting a List using Comparable<T> or a Comparator<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/3137/comparable-and-comparator/10693/sorting-a-list-using-comparablet-or-a-comparatort#t=201608131317475628656) example in [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation)...

Comment: Why are you using `indexOf`?

Comment: Make the thing you want to sort implement `Comparable`. Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html.

Comment: `m.getName() != "Click GUI"` is also incorrect. See [How do I compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a module comparator by implemening `java.util.Comparator` interface and write your sorting logic in it, like:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class ModuleSorter implements Comparator<Module> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Module module1, Module module2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(module2.getName().length()).compareTo(module1.getName().length());
    }

}
```

I am assuming that `myClient.getModules()` returns an implementation of `java.util.List`. The sorting now would be as simple as:

```
final List<Module> moduleList = myClient.getModules();
moduleList.sort(new ModuleSorter());
```

The modules inside `moduleList` are sorted as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using streams:

```
List<String> modules = myClient.getModules().stream()
    .filter(m -> m.isToggled() && !"Click GUI".equals(m.getName()))
    .map(Module::getName)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This assumes `getModules` return some collection that can be streamed.